# windows 7 64 bit crashes after video updaate

Tags: windows-7, windows

Went to play a game and a screen popped up to update my drivers. After I went to manufactures webpage and downloaded drivers I started to install them (ati radeon video card) it got 1/2 popped up a screen that said can not install.

My screen turned black computer shut down. Now all I get is video not supported 128 than blue screen. When I restart I get open normally or system repair. System repair can not fix problem and start normally crashes. How do I uninstall the video drive when I can not get it to even go in safe mode?

Comment: Your problem description is missing details. What webpage did you go to? What drivers did you download? What popped up a screen and what precisely did it say? What happened before your computer shut down? Did it happen right after you finished the diver install? What problem couldn't system repair fix? When precisely does a normal start crash, what happens right before it crashes, and what does the crash itself say?

Comment: Problem was Computer would not start. Went to AMD website for video card drivers ATI Radeon 3850. Pop up said unsupported format then screen went black about 10 seconds later comp shut off. The drivers were about 1/2 to 3/4 done when it popped up and than crashed. System repair said unknown problem video not support than a long line of numbers. Crashes as windows pops up says video not supported 128. Shutting down to protect pc. Shuts down before I can read more.

Comment: After talking to Windows they informed me that it corrupted my operating system and would have to a fresh reinstall. So I backed up files through some sort of system image recover. Am now 1/2 way through fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

After you hear the system beep and before you see the Windows start screen, you need to press F8 (I believe) to get to the Windows Boot Menu. It will allow you to either go to safe mode or to row back to previously know good.

Comment: Tried that only give choice Start Normally or system repair (recommended). Found away to back up files so I'll just reinstall thanks for trying:)